# merge two csv files, command wont print first line

Tags: csv, awk, merge

I have two csv files and a command to merge them but it wont print the first line.

File1.csv

```
1003085,1
1003144,2
1003149,2
1003208,1
101203,1
```

File2.csv

```
131567,489.564273848
2759,489.564273848
33630,58.5245463474
554915,63.4537671111
1003085,74.6
1003144,20.365
1003149,486.39431
```

Wanted output.csv

```
1003085,1,74.6
1003144,2,20.365
1003149,2,486.39431
1003208,1
101203,1
```

The command I am using:

```
awk -F, -v OFS="," 'NR==FNR&&NR>1{a[$1]=$2 FS $3;next} FNR>1{printf "%s%s\n",$0,($1 in a?FS a[$1]:"")}' file2.csv file1.csv > out.csv
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NR>1` means "Number (of) Record" Greater than (>) 1. Remove that and the `FNR>1` (current File Number (of) Record)  and you should be OK.

If you inherited this code, it is probably designed to eliminate printing the header row.

IHTH